# preg: how to write a preg pattern to get domain name from an email?

Tags: javascript, regex, preg-match

From an email address like `something@gmail.com` I want to fetch domain name `gmail.com`.
i want to use that pattern on textbox value in Javascript.

Pease suggest me an optimized and faster preg pattern for above requirement...

Comment: sorry, do you want a preg regex or a JS regex, they are different and potentially incompatible. also, what have you tried?

Comment: I was told that regular expression works faster than string functions. I dont know much about regular expression. :(

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can replace everything up to and including the `@` symbol to get the domain. In Javascript:

```
var email = 'test@gmail.com';
var domain = email.replace(/.*@/, "");
alert(domain);
```

Comment: That won't work, see Jesse Cohen's comment below. There can be multiple @ characters in an email address (albeit between quotation marks)

Comment: thanks for the regex but it will only work for - something.com ( without subdomains) . I have posted a solution extending yours which supports domain fetching from any kind of url ( n number of subdomain level) .

Answer (score 7):

Why not just do this.

```
var email = "something@gmail.com", i = email.indexOf("@");
if (i != -1) {
   email = email.substring(i);
}
```

Regex isn't really required, you could also go `email = email.split("@")[1];`

Comment: To address problem raised by Jesse Cohen, you can use `email.lastIndexOf('@')+1` to get the last `@` position. See https://jsfiddle.net/mx6bqytg/1/

Answer (score 5):

I have just experience a need to implement this and came up with the solution that combines most of already mentioned techniques:

```
var email = "test@test@gmail.com";
var email_string_array = email.split("@");
var domain_string_location = email_string_array.length -1;
var final_domain = email_string_array[domain_string_location];
```

So if email has multiple @ characters then you just need to split email string by "@" and calculate how many elements are there in new created array then 
subtract 1 from it and you can take right element from array with that number.

Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/47yqn/

It has show 100% success for me!

Answer (score 4):

Using a simple string split won't work on addresses like `'abc@abc'@example.com` which is a  valid address (technically). I believe splitting on `@` and taking the *last* element should be fine, because no `@` characters are allowed to appear in the domain.

Or, since you requested, a regex:
`[^@]+$`

Answer (score 3):

A bit cleaner and up-to-date approach:

```
const email = "something@gmail.com"
const domain = email.includes('@') && email.split("@").pop()
```

Domain will be `false` if email doesn't contain @ symbol.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
var extract_company_name = function(email){
  var temp = email.replace(/.*@/, '').split('.');
    return temp[temp.length - 2];
}
extract_company_name(email)
```

this will fetch the domain from any email.

[code in jsbin](https://jsbin.com/pedazizece/edit?html,js,console)

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
\b.*@([A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})\b
```

Or maybe tune it a little replacing `\b`s by `^` and `$`.
With this you can match any domain with A-Z, a-z and 0-9 characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
var email = 'test@gmail.com';
var domain = email.replace(/.*@/, "").split('.')[0];
console.log(domain); // gmail
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this to get domain name from url,email,website,with http started,only domain name

```
var str=inputAddress;
      var patt1 = "(http://|https://|ftp://|www.|[a-z0-9._%+-]+@)([^/\r\n]+)(/[^\r\n]*)?";
var result = str.match(patt1);
var domain=result===null?str:result[2];
return domain.toString().startsWith("www.")?domain.toString().slice(4):domain;
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to make a regex do so much. They easily become prone to errors. In this case, an e-mail like `hello@www.example.com` would give a domain `example.com`, but the correct domain is `www.example.com`.