# Javascript: Extracting local part and domain of an email

Tags: javascript

I have an email in the following format:

```
joe+12312313@aDomain.com
```

First, I need to make sure the email's domain equals to `aDomain.com`
Next, I need to extract everything **before** the `+` sign

It would be nice if I can get a the following object:

```
var objParts = {
        localPart: null,
        domain: null,
        };

console.log(objParts.localPart) // joe
console.log(objParts.domain) // aDomain.com
```

I know we have to use Regex.  I am new to JS.

Comment: You can use simple `split`

Comment: Have you tried/researched anything at all? E.g. [preg: how to write a preg pattern to get domain name from an email?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5181746/218196) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var email = "joe+12312313@aDomain.com";
var objParts = CreateEmailParts(email);

console.log(objParts.localPart);
console.log(objParts.domain);


function CreateEmailParts(email)
{
  if(email)
  {
        var objParts = {
          domain:  email.split('@')[1], // caution: hoping to have the domain follow @ always
          localPart: email.split('+')[0], // caution: hoping to have the ema follow @ always
        };
 return objParts;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pdkvx82d/

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem like you have to validate the generic email format here.

You can just split on the main points, `@` and `+`, and extract the data:

```js
const email = 'joe+12312313@aDomain.com'
const domain = email.split('@').pop()  // split on '@' and get the last item
const local = email.split('+').shift() // split on '+' and get the first item

console.log(domain);
console.log(local);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use simple `split`:

```
var str = "joe+12312313@aDomain.com";
var parts = str.split("@");
var objParts = {
    localPart: parts[0].split('+')[0],
    domain: parts[1],
};
console.log(objParts);
```